# How do I set up the iPhone USB Ethernet Driver?

Tags: 12.04, iphone

I just installed 12.04 (fresh install) and realized I could no longer tether with my iPhone like how I did on 11.10 without any hassle. On 11.10 (to my amazement) all I had to do was turn on USB tethering option in MyWi and my system would automatically connect to the Internet via my phone. What has changed and how can I tether again?

BTW it is an iPhone 3G (jailbroken)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get iPhone USB tethering working again, just install the following packages:

1. `ipheth-utils`.
2. `libimobiledevice-dev`
3. `libimobiledevice-utils`

You can install these packages through `apt-get` command or through the synaptic package manager `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Comment: What's the best way to do this when you don't have any alternative for an internet connection but your actual phone? I mean, I could get off my ass and go into the coffee shop but...

Comment: @boulder_ruby – The best way would be to use your device's wifi tethering to install the necessary software before switching to USB.  On an iPhone, that's (currently) Settings → Personal Hotspot, which is near the top, not far below Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 7):

On top of the steps listed by Mysterio, you may need to use the following command in a terminal window to get it working:

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

Then unplug your phone and plug it back in.  When you plug it back in, a notification should pop up (on your Ubuntu system) saying it has connected to a wired network. (If the notification does not appear, make sure Personal Hotspot is enabled on your phone.)

This works for me with a non-jailbroken iPhone running iOS 5.0 and no additional software on either my laptop or phone.

Comment: This doesn’t work with iPhone 7s and Ubuntu 16.04. All I get is an attempt to connect followed by a pop up warning saying “Ethernet disconnected”

Comment: I get `No device found, is it plugged in?`

Comment: It worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04). Without this didn't work.

Comment: I got `SUCCESS: Unpaired with device. SUCCESS: Unpaired with device because a passcode is set. Please enter the passcode on the device and retry.` How to mention passcode which is set in my case on my hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the `usbmuxd` package solved the issue with iphone 7 and 17.10.

Comment: Only answer that worked for me. Thanks :D

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Did you restart your machine to get it working?