# Ubuntu 12.04 usb iphone 4s tethering

Tags: 12.04, usb, iphone, offline

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't get the tethering to work.
I found many solutions to this problem, but I don't have Internet access except the iPhone.
And most of the fixes are online based or old!

Can I can download the required packages with Windows (which does connect), put those files on a external drive, and fix it that way?

Answer (score 1):

Guess you will need to go to a coffeehaus or library w/ WiFi to download as described in [How do I set up the iPhone USB Ethernet Driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126340/how-do-i-set-up-the-iphone-usb-ethernet-driver) :

- ipheth-utils
- libimobiledevice-dev
- libimobiledevice-utils

if Personal Hotspot was enabled and then you opened a terminal window to do

`idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair`

and then unplugged/replugged your phone with no success.